# Convert a while loop to something reusable

Tags: python

I often find myself using a pattern like this:

```
num_repeats = 123
interval = 12

for _ in xrange(num_repeats):
    result = ...
    if result meets condition:
         break
    time.sleep(interval)

else:
    raise Failed despite multiple attempts
```

Basically, it repeats code until the correct result is returned, or the counter expires.

Although this works, it looks too verbose to me. Is it possible to "parametrize" this loop to a reusable function or context manager, like for example

```
with repeat(num_repeats, interval):
    code
```

Or maybe there's something in the standard library that would do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator which sleeps before returning repeated results.
The advantage is that your caller is still a genuine for loop, with
all the `break`, `continue`, `else` semantics still in tact.

```
def trickle_range(num_repeats, interval):
    yield 0
    for k in xrange(1, num_repeats):
          time.sleep(interval)
          yield k


for k in trickle_range(num_repeats, interval):
    ... do stuff, iterate or break as you like ...
```

Comment: This looks like a most flexible approach. Additional +++ for the name ;)

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to decorate the functions you want to repeat:

```
def repeats_until(num_repeats, interval, condition):
    def deco(f):
        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            for _ in xrange(num_repeats):
                result = f(*args, **kwargs)
                if condition(result):
                    return result
                time.sleep(interval)
        return func
    return deco
```

And then use it like:

```
@repeats_until(3, 5, lambda s: s == "hello")
def take_input():
    return raw_input("Say hello: ")
```

Example (although I can't show the wait!)

```
>>> take_input()
Say hello: foo
Say hello: bar
Say hello: baz
>>> take_input()
Say hello: hello
'hello'
```

Alternatively, to keep the condition with the called function, something like:

```
def repeats(num_repeats, interval):
    def deco(f):
        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            for _ in xrange(num_repeats):
                result = f(*args, **kwargs)
                if result is not None: # or e.g. False if None is valid return
                    return result
                time.sleep(interval)
        return func
    return deco    

@repeats(3, 5)
def take_input(condition):
    s = raw_input("Say hello: ")
    if condition(s):
        return s

ui = take_input(lambda s: s == "hello")
```

This relies on the decorated function returning a value (in this case the implicit `None`) that tells the decorator it isn't finished yet.

Comment: I like the decorator idea, however it's not always possible to wrap the "repeatable" logic in a function, due to scoping issues.

Answer (score 1):

You definately won't be able to use the `with` statement, as python only supplies hooks before and after the code has run, but not one for invoking it, ie. You can't hide a loop within a `with` statement.

A nice approach is to use a lambda function:

```
def repeat(repeats, interval, func):
    for i in xrange(repeats):
        if func(i):
            break
        time.sleep(interval)
```

Which you can then use quite easily:

```
repeat(123, 12, lambda i: condition(i))
```

Or something similar

Comment: One downside is that this approach doesn't actually give you `i` - you could `return i` instead of `break`ing.